# Currency converter with javaScript

Tags: javascript

I am working on a currency converter in javascript and I've run into a problem I didn't think about. So the base currency is USD and I have buttons working for converting it into a few currencies. But then the problem is that when I am not "on" USD and try to convert it's using rates for converting from USD, but it's not converting from USD.

Could it be done with if/elseif or switches? If that's even possible I would have to do so many and I'm not sure if there's an efficient way to do it?

```
$(function() {
var currencyRates = $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=' + access_key,   
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(json) {

        setUSD = function() {
            var USDrate = json.rates.USD;
            console.log("Setting site currency to USD ($)");
            console.log(USDrate);
            var USDsalary;
            var salary = document.getElementById('salarySpan').innerHTML;
            var currencySign = document.getElementById('currencySign').innerHTML;
            var salaryUSD = salary * USDrate;
            document.getElementById('salarySpan').innerHTML = salaryUSD.toFixed(2);
            document.getElementById('currencySign').innerHTML = '€';

        setEUR = function() {
            var EURrate = json.rates.EUR;
            console.log("Setting site currency to EUR (€)");
            var salary = document.getElementById('salarySpan').innerHTML;
            var currencySign = document.getElementById('currencySign').innerHTML;
            var salaryEUR = salary * EURrate;
            document.getElementById('salarySpan').innerHTML = salaryEUR.toFixed(2);
            document.getElementById('currencySign').innerHTML = '€';
        }
       }}
   });
})
```

Comment: @Carcigenicate The problem is that if I switch from the base currency of USD  to EUR for example, it works. But then when I then try to switch to GBP it takes the rate for USD->GBP and uses that for the conversion of EUR->GPB

Comment: Probably best to not have USD rates hard coded in. Have a variable, which when you change base currency the variable is then set to that currency. then you would use json.rates.BASE  which would be set to USD by default but then change based on which currency you select. Also its probably best to just get the exchange rates and then use them in a separate function to convert that way you have less hard-coded functions/variables.

Comment: @CallumR The problem is that the API i use only has the option to choose the base currency of USD

Answer (score 0):

I actually fixed it, a lot simpler than I thought. I just put the var salary outside of the specific currency functions